# Find all numbers divisible by 25, that begin with 6.

Tags: arithmetic

please, help me solve this problem:

> Find all numbers divisible by 25, that begin with 6.

Regards.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? I assume that you mean "begin with a 6" in base 10 representation.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Of course it's base $10$! I notice that you didn't query whether $25$ was in base $10$. That's because base $10$ is understood, unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @TonyK To be an absolute pedant about this, this question could be in almost any base whatsoever that has 2, 5, 6 among the digits. Base 10 is a very reasonable guess, but in the absence of Tom confirming, it's still just a guess.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: Base $10$ is not just a "very reasonable guess", it's the _default assumption_. (And if it's pedantry that you want, the post has to be in base $10$, doesn't it? The only question is what does $10$ mean.)

Comment: @TonyK I somehow expected that last part to come from Geoff rather than from you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An integer is divisible by $25$ if and only if the last two digits are $00$, $25$, $50$, or $75$. Therefore, there are four possibilities.

$$\pm6X00,\ \pm6X25,\ \pm6X50,\ \pm6X75$$

where $X$ is any sequence of digits, perhaps empty.

(Don't forget the negative integers as well! Though you could quibble about whether a number like $-625$ starts with a minus sign or with a $6$.)

@GeoffRobinson makes the excellent point that this works for decimal, base 10, representation. This would need to be changed for other number systems.

Answer (score 2):

They are all numbers of the form
$$6X\dots XYY$$
where $X\dots X$ could be anything, and $YY=00, 25, 50, 75$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume base 10 (decimal), and that they have to be positive.

There are infinitely many such numbers. For any $n > 1$, you can just do $6 \times 10^n$ to get one such number, then keep adding 25 and stop short of $7 \times 10^n$ to get all such numbers with $n + 1$ digits.

Do note that $625 = 25^2 = 5^4$. Are there other powers of 5 that begin with 6? That's a slightly more interesting question. (There's at least one other).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the rules of modular-arithmetic you can write:
$$z=a_0+a_1\cdot 10+...+a_n\cdot 10^n$$
With $a_n=6$ 
The number $z$ is divisible for $25$ if $$a_0+10\cdot a_1$$ is a multiple of $25$
Indeed $$a_0\equiv a_0\pmod {25}$$
$$10\cdot a_0\equiv 10\cdot a_0\pmod {25}$$
While the other digits are divisible for $25$
Indeed $$10^2\equiv 0\pmod {25}$$
And etc...